# Go: "instance" redeclared in this block

Tags: go

I have these two files:

**daoFactory.go**

```
package dao

import "sync"

type daoFactory struct {}

var instance *daoFactory

//some functions
```

**fakeProvisionDao.go**

```
package dao

import (
    "sync"
    "model"
)

type provisionDao struct {
}

var instance *provisionDao

//some functions
```

Both are in the same package: `dao`.

I get this error:

> "instance" redeclared in this block

Obviously, the cause is that `instance` variable is declared in both files. I'm beggining in Go programming and I don't know how should I handle with this error.

Comment: Don't declare `instance` the second time.

Comment: Hi, again. But where should I declare it? Is there any convention for handle with this?

Comment: Have you read through the docs yet? [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/)

Comment: Or just rename each to something other than `instance`?

Comment: `instance` is a vague variable name. What is it an instance of? You're using the same variable name for two different types. Its almost like defining a class with two class variables that have different types; of course the compiler will complain. Either 1. put your structs in different packages and not in the same `dao` package or 2. rename your variables.

Comment: I come from Java background. This is because to have two variables with the same name in different files is not strange for me. But now,  I know that it is not possible in Go. I have named it "instance" because I was trying to implement singleton pattern.

Comment: @bigdestroyer: A general tip, don't write java in Go. Go isn't OO in the same way as java, and the patterns one would use in java are often counter-productive in Go.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Files have no real meaning for go, unlike in java, python and many others, they are just for you to organize your code as you see fit.

In go variables are visible `package` wide, that means that both declartions of `instance` are variables with package wide visibility. Hence the compiler complains about having two global variables with the same name.

Rename any one of your two instance variables and it will compile.

Reading the links in the comments above is highly recommend ;-)